# How to create a cell with text AND containing value of another cell?

Tags: excel

What I need is the following:

Let's say the A columns containts the image file names and its extension. For example:

Cell A2: Flowers.png

I want to create an associative column B with entry B2 containing:

```
<img src="/uploads/Flowers.png">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `=CONCATENATE("<img src=""/uploads/", A2, """>")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings with `&`. In cell B2:

`="<img src=""/uploads/" & A2 & """>"`

Note that you escape the double quote (") in your string with a double-double quote ("").